# How do I link highlighting groups in a vim colour scheme?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to clean up a colour scheme that I'm making for vim by linking some highlighting groups but I can't get the linking to work.

Here is a sample of my vim script:

```
highlight Error            ctermbg=161
highlight link ErrorMsg    Error
```

The `ErrorMsg` still has the default background colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're clearing the settings for `ErrorMsg` before the link, otherwise the link will fail.

```
highlight Error            ctermbg=161
highlight ErrorMsg         NONE
highlight link ErrorMsg    Error
```

Comment: If you use `!` after highlight e.g., `highlight! link ErrorMsg Error`, you achieve the same effect without having to add `highlight ErrorMsg NONE`.